# Get date difference for different rows of a id for multiple ids in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I want to get the difference of dates on 2 consecutive rows if the id is the same.

A simple code for that would be:

```
for(i in 2:nrow(Data))
{
  if(id[i]==id[i-1]
  {
   dated[i]-dated[i-1]
  }
}
```

But this being in a loop takes ages to execute. Is there any quicker way to run this kind of a code on over 2 million rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'id', get the difference (`diff`) of 'dated' column

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(datedifference = diff(dated)), id]
```

Comment: Hi, thankyou for the solution. while this works perfectly and gives a table, I want to add this as a column to an already existing data frame. Could you guide me how to proceed with that?

Comment: @eclairs Iin that case do `setDT(df1)[, datedifference := c(NA, diff(dated)), id]`